# How do I access each value in array?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I have attempted numerous times trying access each value in a array. The array contains the database results retrieved from the select query.

```
$query = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT orderStatus FROM customerOrders");                     
foreach ($query->results() as $orderered) {

   $result_array = array($orderered);
 //print_r($result_array);

$orderData = array_map(function ($object) { return $object->orderStatus; },                $result_array);

  $test = json_decode(json_encode($result_array), true);



  $ORvalue = serialize($test);


  $ORvalue2 = unserialize($ORvalue);


  $orderValueNEW = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $ORvalue2);


  print_r($orderValueNEW);//debug 


}//close foreach loop
```

Result it prints are:

```
Array ( [orderStatus] => 0 ) 
Array ( [orderStatus] => 0 ) 
Array ( [orderStatus] => 0 ) 
Array ( [orderStatus] => 1 ) 
Array ( [orderStatus] => 1 )
```

Comment: [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/array_walk_recursive) maybe? To me it is not clear which values you want to acces and how the conventional methods are not helping

Comment: I keep getting a "Array ( )" there's nothing in the array at all. The loop is adding the database values in the array.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing should work to retrieve each row, but if you want to access the `orderStatus` value, you can do this with your result array:

```
 foreach ($result_array as $resultRow) {
    echo $resultRow['orderStatus'];
 }
```

That should work, if that's what you mean. If you want to access the `orderStatus` value in the first loop, you can refer to it as `$row['orderStatus']`. Or, if you do a `SELECT *` in your query and you want to go through all values from the query, you can just make another loop like `foreach ($row as $column => value) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to just print the values and not the associate key/value pairs?

Changing

```
$result_array[] = $row;
```

to

```
$result_array[] = $row['orderStatus'];
```

should do the trick.

Comment: how do I count the total values in the array? All the array shows me is the first position of the array like:                                                                        Array
(
    [0] => 0
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
)

Comment: You can use count() to get the number of items in the array. This won't sum the values for you though.